# Login credentials security PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security

Hi I am a beginner and I am looking to develop a website in PHP that has login for members. I want to know how can I make sure that the username and password won't get hacked. I mean what measures should I take to prevent this scenario. I have heard people talking about MD5 and SHA but I dont really know how to implement them. I am using mysql as backend.

thank you very much.
I would appreciate any efforts

Comment: Read up on SQL-injection and XSS-attacks. These are 2 common techniques used to do a lot of bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save in the database the password hashed with an hash algo + a salt **unique** for each record.

Example: `$pass = sha256/512( $pass . md5($user) . WEBSITE_SALT_KEY );`

But this won't save you possibility hijack attempts. The best way to guarantee a good security is to use `SSL`

Comment: so is this secure, can it be reverse engineered. because there are websites that decrypt sha256

Comment: @dgamma3: it's not possible to "decrypt" sha256. The only possibility is to generate all the possibilities until you find the right one, and you can have pre-compiled tables of such values, but if you use a decent salt it's infeasible to find a valid value.

Comment: @dgamma3, hash functions are not encryption algorithms, therefore they cannot be decrypted, because there's nothing to decrypt. They contain no information. If you're thinking about sites such as "SHA1 decrypter" (or whatever the name is, I forgot it), then these sites are nothing more than a database mapping stings that the users submitted to their SHA1 hashes. If, however, you add more than the user's password to the hash function, these site will obviously not "work" anymore, since they store only the password strings that the users contributed, without anything added to them.

Comment: @yes123 what do u mean by SALT and can we use MD5 instead of SHA

Comment: @koool: for extensive explanation of SALT go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) . Also note md5 is not safe and you should use sha1. Also if this answer helped you think to mark it as the accpeted answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use MD5. [It's broken](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/12/forging_ssl_cer.html). Prefer SHA algorithms instead (both SHA1 and SHA256 should be more than adequate for hashing passwords).

Whenever you register a user, instead of storing the password they give you as "plain text" in the database, apply a hash function on the password. What this does is basically to take the plain text password and generate a [cryptographic checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of that password. This checksum is a string of bytes that cannot be transformed again in the original password. So, if you store the password hashed in the database, then, theoretically, nobody will be able to find out what the user's password really is.

This however means that not even you will know what the password is. Therefore, when the user needs to authenticate, you will need to apply the same hash function on the password they give you, then compare with the hashes you have in the database.

Example:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $_REQUEST['password']);
```

When the user registers, you store the `$hash` instead of the password in the database. Next, when they try to login:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $_REQUEST['password']);
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ... AND password = '{$hash}'");
```

If a hacker obtains the contents of your database now, they won't be able to find out what the users' passwords are.

As an added security measure, as yes123 points out, it's a good idea to add more than just the password string to the hash function. So instead of just `$hash = hash('sha256', $_REQUEST['password'])`, it's a good idea to also add the user ID for example: `$hash = hash('sha256', $userId . $_REQUEST['password'])`, so that the resulting string will be more secure.

---

Now that you secured the contents stored in the database, the next step is to secure your web forms.

What you should be aware of is the [man in the middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). This basically means that if you have a form in which the user enters their password and simply sends it to your server, it's trivial for someone snooping on the transfer to read the user's password in plain text as it travels from their computer to your server.

To prevent this, use `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP` for the pages asking the user for their password.

---

There are many, many ways in which an attacker could exploit your code, and this advice only scratches the surface. The basic rule of thumb is: *never trust the user*. The current user of your site might be the hacker himself, trying to exploit your code by going to `a.php?id='; TRUNCATE users; --` if you don't escape the input before inserting it in the database.

If you're really serious about security, you should check out the [Common Weakness Enumeration](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/slices/2000.html). Many of these weaknesses apply to PHP. The most attacks you might face though are [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Prepare for these before anything, by always escaping user input, and never trusting what the user sends you.

Comment: just to extrapolate your point about adding the userID to the hashed password. If your adding a new user you wont know what his/hers ID will be. To figure this out, use something like 'SELECT ID FROM users ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1'. more info check here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

Comment: Or even better, get the MySQL last insert ID, to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: care to explain, maybe a link. I have tried implementing your method here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176821/php-hash-function-checking-database) but it isn't working. thanks

Comment: You can use either [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) from PHP (or its `PDO` counterpart, [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)), or you can use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) MySQL function.

Comment: @Radu I understood everything else that you said but could you help me on how can I use Https instead of http

Comment: @koool, that's a server issue, nothing to do with PHP itself. You should try posting a separate question asking how to use HTTPS on your server, if you can't find a tutorial about it or a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

another thing you need to remember is the posibility of SQL injection. This can be prevented pretty easily though with a built in php function

example of the function in use:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start reading [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) you'll find many examples and best practices